# What percentage of applicants to Harvard (or another well known R1 university) are international?

Tags: application, international-students

Is there anything known about what percentage of applications to Harvard's undergraduate programs comes from international applicants? (If not about Harvard, is something known about similar US R1 universities?)

I seem to easily find information of such statistics for the admitted students but it seems hard to find information on the applicants. (I don't think the one can be easily used to deduce information about the other. I expect a strong bias towards US students in admissions.)

Comment: I don't think there would be a source for that information besides the institution itself.

Comment: @Bryan, right, so have any famous R1 universities ever published such data?

Comment: A brief remark: You may be able to pour over the various court documents for the recent Supreme Court case that Harvard lost. But it may be slow going. https://www.supremecourt.gov/docket/docketfiles/html/public/20-1199.html

Comment: State universities may be easier to locate this information for as they are part of the government and subject to disclosure laws.

Comment: But like, yes, US universities admit more American students than international students. This isn't a secret, nor nefarious, so you're not going to uncover anything we don't know.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, I wasn't calling anything nefarious. I was just curious to know. Unfortunately they do seem to be hiding this in general. Let's hope that there is some famous R1 university that is more open about the process and can lend some insight (I expect that many of the students applying to one top university will also be applying to several other top university so data from one probably quite accurately approximates the others.) (Or as pointed out by user176372 perhaps some court case will help uncover these statistics.)

Comment: I'd be interested in data of State universities as well. Although I doubt they tell much about the more famous universities. They are just not that famous internationally and so I expect they get a lot less international applicants. BTW I just realized that The College Board (SAT) probably has a lot of data on this as well. Again I don't know whether they ever published any statistics on this.

Comment: @Kvothe They may get fewer, but the West Coast state schools receive plenty of Asian attention. And to be honest, probably fewer people taking "moonshots" for Harvard, MIT, etc. So the data may be more meaningful as to students that are well-suited for that institution. However, I'm still not sure about "hiding," I think it is fairly well-known they admit fewer international students than domestic.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, again only mean that they are "hiding it" in the sense that they are not making the data available. It might be "well known" as you say. But despite being "well known" nothing is actually known about it at the moment. It could also be that they are not biased in this regard. At the moment we don't know either way because their is no data available to analyze. I'm sure people have asked before. And I suspect a conscious choice has been made in not making this data available. But we cannot know this "fact" whether it is "well known" or not without the data.

Answer (score 6):

As an example, the [University of California](https://www.universityofcalifornia.edu/about-us/information-center/admissions-residency-and-ethnicity) publishes such data.  UC Berkeley and UCLA are consistently some of the highest ranked public research universities in the US, and usually ranked very high among US and world universities overall.  (For instance, in the [2022-2023 US News global university rankings](https://www.usnews.com/education/best-global-universities/rankings), Berkeley was ranked #4 in the world, behind Harvard, MIT and Stanford, and just ahead of Oxford, so I think they meet your criteria of "well known" / "famous".  UCLA is #14 on that list, and UCSD is #20.)

For Berkeley in 2023, the numbers were:

```
               Total        International (%)
Applied        125,910       21,855 (17%)
Admitted       14,677        1,167 (8%)
Admit rate     11.6%         5.3%
Enrolled       6,641         615 (9%)
```

If you can wait a year or so: a question about applications, admits and enrolls by domestic / international status was just added to the [Common Data Set](https://commondataset.org/) for 2023-2024 (see section C1). Like many institutions, Harvard [publishes](https://oira.harvard.edu/common-data-set/) their CDS data submission each year, but they probably haven't completed the 2023-2024 data yet, and that site is only up to 2022-2023 for which that question was not included.

Comment: Of note, public universities skew towards in-state (domestic) students since tuition is significantly higher otherwise. For Berkeley, it's an [additional $34,200/year](https://financialaid.berkeley.edu/how-aid-works/student-budgets-cost-of-attendance/). Second, as a state taxpayer-funded body, they are mandated to serve state residents. Seats are [guaranteed for 9% of California high school graduates](https://admission.universityofcalifornia.edu/admission-requirements/freshman-requirements/california-residents/statewide-guarantee/) in the UC system.

Comment: Perhaps you could include the domestic rates for comparison?

Answer (score 3):

As another (non-US) example, the [University of Cambridge](https://www.cam.ac.uk) publishes extensive [admissions statistics](https://www.undergraduate.study.cam.ac.uk/apply/statistics). According to the report covering the [2022 admissions cycle](https://www.undergraduate.study.cam.ac.uk/sites/www.undergraduate.study.cam.ac.uk/files/publications/undergrad_admissions_statistics_2022_cycle.pdf), the breakdown was (Table 2.1)<sup>1</sup>

|  | Applications (%) | Offers (%) | Admitted (%)<sup>2</sup> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Domestic | 66.4 | 76.5 | 79.2 |
| International | 33.6 | 23.5 | 20.8 |

Table 3.2 in the report provides a further breakdown by country of origin.

---

<sup>1</sup> The definition of domestic/international here is based on whether the applicant is liable to pay 'home' or 'international' tuition fees. The [rules are complex](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/eligibility-for-home-fee-status-and-student-support-in-england/) but broadly 'home' students are those who have been resident in the UK for at least 3 years before starting the course. Table 2.1 also has information about the schools students are coming from: thus, some 'international' applicants are already at schools in the UK, while some 'domestic' applicants may be applying from abroad.

<sup>2</sup> Most offers are made before applicants have completed school, and so they are conditional on particular grades being achieved. Only about 80% of people who are offered a place ultimately take it up - either because they fail to get the grades, or because they decide to go elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I have upvoted your answer. (Since there are many possible answers concerning different universities I'm not accepting an answer yet for now.)